# Emails not received for consistent API Requests

Tags: rest-api, email, visual-workflow, email-alert

**Scenario:** Inserting Cases via standard SF REST API to receive an Email Response. The Email is sent via Flow (After Insert/Update) + EmailAlert. The REST APIs are being sent **consistently** (i.e., one after the other, **immediately** - consistent POST submits/clicks via Workbench).

**Issue:** Email Responses are not being received for each Case created. Screenshot below (missing Cases 01030349, 01030352) -

[image: Email Responses in Inbox]

Please see below for troubleshooting -

- Debug Logs show that email was sent for **every** Case - **WF_EMAIL_SENT|Reference:XYZ|Recipient:...**
- Email Deliverability is set to '**All**'
- **No email** in **Spam folder** for the **missing** Cases
- Further troubleshooting, **added** a 'SingleEmailMessage' Action after EmailAlert to 'Log Email on Send'. This is **also** logging the email on the Case (even though actual email is not received).

Are there **limits** to how many outbound emails are processed/queued by the Salesforce Mailing Service for multiple requests processed in a few seconds?

Any help/direction is appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: Are all of the recipient emails the same?

Comment: [Email logs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_logs_edit.htm&type=5) are your friend